Postgres "Password Authentication Failed" trying to run npm typeorm migrations

On Windows WSL

I have a Node TypeScript application that runs on my local machine but also connects to a local Postgres database that gets created in Docker. So the DB is in Docker but the app is on my local machine.
when I npm run start:dev it will init the db with the docker-compose.yaml, then use npm typeorm to run the migrations, then nx to serve the application.

My init-db script is successfully spinning up the Docker Postgres instance and creates the db

when trying to run the migrations I'm getting the following error:


Error during migration run:
error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
...........
{
  length: 104,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '321',
  routine: 'auth_failed'
}

all the passwords and configurations are correct in my env files
got the container IP for the postgres instance and tried to connect to it directly through terminal psql command, and it would time out. the only way to get into the db through psql was to actually go to the terminal within the Docker application inside the container.
i think the most obvious solution is to Dockerize all the things but that can't be done right now with the team I'm working on. All my other team members are on Mac and have no issues, the only difference in our setups is that I'm on Windows WSL.
Is there perhaps some kind of permissions configuration I need to do in Docker to allow local applications outside of the container to connect??
// docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./init-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

// .env file
....
# LOCAL DB
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=secret
DB_NAME=tracker

// ormconfig.ts
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();

export default new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
  port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT) || 5432,
  username: process.env.DB_USER || 'postgres',
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'secret',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'tracker',
  entities: [process.env.ENV === 'local' ? 'dist/**/entities/**/*.js' : 'src/**/entities/**/*.js'],
  migrations: [process.env.ENV === 'local' ? 'dist/**/migrations/**/*.js' : 'src/**/migrations/**/*.js'],
  synchronize: false,
  ssl: process.env.ENV !== 'local',
});

// package.json scripts
// running npm run start:dev
"scripts": {
    "start:dev": "docker-compose up -d && npm run migration:run && nx run-many -t serve",
    "typeorm": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
    "migration:run": "nx build redacted-backend && npm run typeorm -- --dataSource=apps/redacted-backend/ormconfig.ts migration:run",
  },


npm installed all deps
npm, node, nvm all up to date
clearing out docker containers between attempts
tried using localhost and 127.0.0.1 and postgresdb and <container-ip> for the connection string
tried using "password" everywhere for the postgres_password instead of "secret" since "password" is the default
uninstalled and reinstalled postgres in WSL terminal
manually set postgres password thru psql in the Docker terminal


The file you need to be looking in is pg_hba.conf. Read the information at the link.

Try opening a port different than 5432 in your DB container, say 5000.
// docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./init-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh
    ports:
      - '5432:5000'

And update the rest of your code accordingly to use the port 5000.
